# Perl, Split string by specific pattern

Tags: perl, parsing

I found how to split a string by whitespaces, but that only takes into an account a single character.  In my case, I have comments pasted into a file that includes newlines and whitespaces.  I have them separated by this string: [|]

So I need to split my $string into an array for example, where $string =

```
This is a comment.
This is a newline.    
This is the end[|]This is second comment.
This is second newline.    
[|]Last comment
```

Gets split into $array[0], $array[1], and $array[2] which include the newlines and whitespaces.  Separated by [|]

Every example I find on the web uses a single character, such as space or newline, to split strings.  In my case I have to use a more specific identifier, which is why I selected [|] but having troubles splitting it by this.

I have tried to limit it to parse by a single '|' character with this code:

```
my @words = split /|/, $string;
foreach my $thisline (@words) {
    print "This line = '" . $thisline . "'\n";
```

But this seems to split the entire string, character-by-character into @words.

Answer (score 2):

`[`, `|`, and `]` are all special characters in regular expressions -- `|` is used to separate options, and `[…]` are used to specify character sets. Using an unquoted `|` makes the expression match the empty string (more specifically: the empty string or the empty string), causing it to match and split on every character boundary. These characters must be escaped to use them literally in an expression:

```
my @words = split /\[\|\]/, $string;
```

Since all the lines makes this visually confusing, you should probably use `m{}` quotes instead of `//`, and `\Q…\E` to quote a range of characters instead of a separate backslash for each one. (This is functionally identical, it's just a little easier to read.)

```
my @words = split m{\Q[|]\E}, $string;
```

Comment: Thank you!  But does m{} only allow me to split by a single character, or can I use it to split via (for instance) three characters:  [|]  ?

Comment: Works like magic.  I obviously need to take a crash course into regex.  Up to this point I have avoided it because it's difficult for my mind to read, with all the symbols.  But now that I see it in action, it's hard for me to avoid it!

Tried to upvote your answer but I don't have enough reputation as a new user, so I'll say again: thank you very much!  Sorry if this is a duplicate question, I searched..

Comment: @duskwuff: If you want to specify an operator then `qr/.../` is more appropriate than `m/.../` as there is no actual matching happening. But I prefer a bare `/.../`, which offers the reminder that this is a regex pattern without any extraneous noise.

Comment: `split` uses regular expressions. Any regex can be used. See `perldoc perlre` for more details. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html